# Manage staff permissions in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to every user who is staff be able to see one certain model of my app as it would be related to it.

Instead to overwrite the save function in that model to get every staff user and relate them to the instance of that model through a Forneign Key I want to modify the permissions of the staff users to allow them to see the instances of that especific model in the admin interface.

Any clues on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need Object-level permissions. Take a look at django-guardian package https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian